# break up buffer into size rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have an observable get data from stream each time at size 512 each next I have to break it up to 200 char at other observable and keep [12] char in other buffer to concatenate with next block, I solve it by using new subject and for loop, I believe there maybe a better, more pretty solution.

received Observable ----------------------------------------

- 1st next   [512] -------> **[112]**  [200] [200] -------> [200] [200]
- 2nd next [512][**112**] --> [24][200][200] [88+**112**]  --> [200] [200]
- 3rd next [512][24] --> [136] [200] [76+124] .....
- nth iteration  [512][194] --> [106][200][200][106+94] --> [200][200][200]
- n+1th [512][6].......

```js
maxValueSize = 200
this._sreamRecord$.subscribe(
    {
        next: (val) => {
            const bufferToSend: Buffer = Buffer.concat([completationBuffer, val])
            for (let i = 0; i < bufferToSend.length; i += maxValueSize) {
                if (bufferToSend.length - i > maxValueSize) {
                    bufferStreamer.next(bufferToSend.slice(i, i + maxValueSize))
                } else {
                    completationBuffer = bufferToSend.slice(i, i + maxValueSize)
                }
            }
        },
        complete() {
            if (completationBuffer.length) {
                bufferStreamer.next(completationBuffer)
            }
            bufferStreamer.complete()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Please share your code and how you are trying to do this currently.

Comment: What happens to the other 100 bytes? 12 + 200 + 200 = 412

Comment: miss calculation the remain is 112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider a solution along these lines

```
const splitInChunksWithRemainder = (remainder: Array<any>) => {
    return (streamRecord: Array<any>) => {
        const streamRecordWithRemainder = remainder.concat(streamRecord);
        let chunks = _.chunk(streamRecordWithRemainder, maxValueSize);
        const last = chunks[chunks.length - 1];
        let newRemainder = [];
        if (last.length != maxValueSize) {
            newRemainder = chunks[chunks.length - 1];
            chunks.length = chunks.length - 1;
        }
        return {chunks, newRemainder};
    };
}

let f = splitInChunksWithRemainder([]);

this._sreamRecord$.pipe(
    switchMap(s => {
        const res = f(s);
        f = splitInChunksWithRemainder(res.newRemainder);
        return from(res.chunks);
    })
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

The idea is to split each `streamRecord` with `lodash` `chunk` function after having concatenated the previous *remainder*, i.e. the array left as tail from the split of the previous `streamRecord`.

This is done using the function `splitInChunksWithRemainder`, which is an *higher level function*, i.e. a function which returns a function, in this case after having set the `remainder` coming from the previous split.

**UPDATE after comment**

If you need to emit also the ***last*** `newRemainder`, than you can consider a slightly more complex solution such as the following

```
const splitInChunksWithRemainder = (remainder: Array<any>) => {
    return (streamRecord: Array<any>) => {
        const streamRecordWithRemainder = remainder.concat(streamRecord);
        let chunks = _.chunk(streamRecordWithRemainder, maxValueSize);
        const last = chunks[chunks.length - 1];
        let newRemainder = [];
        if (last.length != maxValueSize) {
            newRemainder = chunks[chunks.length - 1];
            chunks.length = chunks.length - 1;
        }
        return {chunks, newRemainder};
    };
}

const pipeableChain = () => (source: Observable<any>) => {
    let f = splitInChunksWithRemainder([]);
    let lastRemainder: any[];
    return source.pipe(
        switchMap(s => {
            const res = f(s);
            lastRemainder = res.newRemainder;
            f = splitInChunksWithRemainder(lastRemainder);
            return from(res.chunks);
        }),
        concat(defer(() => of(lastRemainder)))
    )
}

_streamRecord$.pipe(
    pipeableChain()
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

We have introduced the `pipeableChain` function. In this function we save the remainder which is returned by the execution of `splitInChunksWithRemainder`. Once the source Observable completes, we add a last notification via the `concat` operator. 
As you see, we have also to use the `defer` operator to make sure we create the Observable only when the Observer subscribes, i.e. after the source Observable completes. Without `defer` the Observable passed to `concat` as parameter would be created when the source Observable is initially subscribed, i.e. when `lastRemainder` is still undefined.

Comment: at complete the newRemainder will not be emitted.

Comment: The fastest way to get the the ***last*** `newRemainder` is to change the code from `return from(res.chunks);` to `return from(res);`. In this way for every notification of the Observable (and therefore also for the last one) you would get both the `chunks` and the `remainder`. If you really need an Observable which emits the ***last*** `newRemainder` as its last value before completing, than you can look at my updated answer.