# How to convert a stream of variable length packets into fixed length packets in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable

I'm new to RxJS.

Given the following stream

```
[ 'foo ', 'bar', ' b', 'az 12', '3', '4567' ]
```

I want to transform it into a fixed size packets (say of 3 bytes) + the remainder

```
['foo', ' ba', 'r b', 'az ', '123', '456', '7']
```

In real life it's actually a Buffer of binary data.

I'm wondering what's the idiomatic RxJS way to do it.

The trivial way I found is:

```
from([ 'foo ', 'bar', ' b', 'az 12', '3', '4567' ])
.pipe(
    Rx.concatMap(v => from(v)),
    Rx.bufferCount(3),
    Rx.map(v => v.join(''))
)
.subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

It seems wasteful to split everything into a single chars, so another way I found was to use *.slice()* which might be better, but a lot more verbose.

```
const bufferToSize = (chunkSize) => (source) =>
    Observable.create(subscriber => {
        let buffer = new Buffer('')

        return source.subscribe({
            next: (value) => {
                buffer += value

                while (buffer.length > chunkSize) {
                    subscriber.next(buffer.slice(0, chunkSize))
                    buffer = buffer.slice(chunkSize, buffer.length)
                }
            },
            complete: () => {
                subscriber.next(buffer)
                subscriber.complete()
            }
        })
    });

from([ 'foo ', 'bar', ' b', 'az 12', '3', '4567' ])
    .pipe(bufferToSize(3))
    .subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

both return expected results

```
foo
 ba
r b
az
123
456
7
```

Is there a better way to do that? or at least more idiomatic way?

Thanks

Comment: I think your first solution is great, slice wouldn't perform better anyway ;-)

Comment: I think the first solution is the easiest as well. Note that you could use instead of `concatMap(v => from(v))` just `concatMap(v => v)` or `concatAll()`.

Comment: If you are puzzled by emitting every single byte, then you may consider the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863041/break-up-buffer-into-size-rxjs/51918027#51918027).

Comment: I think the first solution is fine *only up to a point* - it will take the whole value in then output it, which is fine for small values / streams, but if it was a continuing stream of data of indeterminate length, it would never emit. The buffer.slice option is more scalable - heavier weight if you don't need that scalability, but essentially would work no matter how long the stream. I can't think of another option besides the two you have listed though...

Answer (score 1):

Your first Option is perfect(except for `from()`, just use `v => v`).

@Mark said it will wait for the observable complete to take whole value, but it`s not. It just waits for 3 chars gathered and then emit the buffer.

I created delayed version to show you this is continuous stream.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/buffer-mxsltx?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50